# Can my /public directory be a symlink with rails 3 + passenger 3 + nginx 0.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm putting together a rails deployment where the public directory is a 
symlink to another directory on the system. This is with passenger 3 on 
nginx .8. It does't seem to like that setup. Nginx always follows symlinks by default, so AFAIK it's not a matter of doing the equivalent of Apache's +FollowSymLinks.

**update**

Looks like this is covered here: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#application_detection

> Note that Phusion Passenger for Nginx
>   does not resolve any symlinks in the
>   root path. So for example, suppose
>   that your root points to
>   /home/www/example.com, which in turn
>   is a symlink to
>   /webapps/example.com/public. Phusion
>   Passenger for Nginx will check for
>   /home/www/config/environment.rb, not
>   /webapps/example.com/config/environment.rb.
>   This file of course doesn’t exist, and
>   as a result Phusion Passenger will not
>   activate itself for this virtual host,
>   and you’ll most likely see some output
>   generated by the Nginx default
>   directory handler such as a Forbidden
>   error message.
>
> Detection of Rack applications happens
>   through the same mechanism, exception
>   that Phusion Passenger will look for
>   config.ru instead of
>   config/environment.rb.

So I wonder if some proper symlinking of config.ru might do the trick.

Comment: Define "It does't seem to like that setup." What you are trying to do should work.

Comment: I just added an update with some info from the documentation -- looks like it's not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is not possible to use a symlinked public directory. The only workaround I can imagine is to symlink any file and directory inside of the public dir.

```
# public folder: /data/public
# app folder: /webapp/
mkdir -p /webapp/public && ln -sf /data/public/* /webapp/public/
```

For every new file or directory in /data/public you have to run this command again.

Comment: Even though the other answer was more valuable to me, I'm marking this one as "correct" because it's sort of a more literal correct answer to the question I asked (and also that way I can give "honorable mention" :) )

Answer (score 10):

Can't you use the following:

```
mount --bind /original_path /your_ngnix_root_path
```

instead of using symlinks? For ngnix it would be a usual directory, why it will point to another directory as you wanted it to be.

Comment: This works! And it's something I didn't know about at all. I wonder if there are any side effects to be wary of… seems like something that low level could end up being too good to be true. Any more thoughts on this?

Comment: mount --bind works on the same level as simple mount of hdd or other storage media, so it is transparent to user level and no side effects should raise in your case.

Comment: I noticed that I can't do a `rm -rf` on a dir with such a mount point, I have to unmount it first. So it does add that step to my deploy recipe (which is fine).

Comment: Do not use `rm -rf <target_dir>` - the directory is busy being mountpoint. Use `rm -rf <target_dir>/*` to delete everything inside the directory.

Comment: What about loosing the 'mount' after rebooting?

Comment: Just put it in /etc/rc.local or something similar. It is like "How about starting the server after reboot?" or "How about mounting network disks after reboot?" - it is part of your server configuration, do it in init scripts!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with the guide linked below.

1. Create your rails app in `/var/www/html`
2. Delete `default`.
3. Edit the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file
4. symlink to `sites-enabled`
5. Restart nginx

[How to Deploy Ruby on Rails with Passenger and Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-to-deploy-ruby-on-rails-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04_593707[1])