# Nginx + passenger do not resolve soft link when deploying app to a host root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am trying different ways of deploying Rails app (redmine, to be specific) with nginx and Passenger. Let's say that I have it installed in `/var/local/railapps/redmine-1.1`.

When I deploy as sub-uri, I can make the soft link just to `public` folder:

```
sudo ln -s /var/local/railapps/redmine-1.1/public /var/www/rails/redmine
```

and add to `server` block in `nginx.conf`:

```
root /var/www/rails;
passenger_enabled on;
passenger_base_uri /redmine;
```

With this, redmine can access folders on the same level as `public`, for example, `/var/local/railapps/redmine-1.1/config`.

On the other hand, Passenger does not resolve soft links when it is installed to a host root (according to [this guide](http://modrails.org/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html)):

```
sudo ln -s /var/local/railapps/redmine-1.1/public /var/www/rails/redmine

root /var/www/rails/redmine;
passenger_enabled on;
```

I am getting the error from Passenger: `No such file or directory - config/environment.rb` in root `/var/www/rails`, which means that it tries to get relative paths not from the link target, but from the link itself. If I make the link to the main redmine folder, the whole thing works:

```
sudo ln -s /var/local/railapps/redmine-1.1 /var/www/rails/redmine

root /var/www/rails/redmine/public;
passenger_enabled on;
```

So, the question is, why is Passenger able to resolve softlinks in "sub-uri" mode, but is not in "host root" mode? Are there some additional settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not do that in "host root mode" in order to support Capistrano-style deployment directories. This is documented in detail in [this section of the documentation of the Apache version](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#application_detection). The Apache version allows customizing the symlink resolving behavior (for backward compatibility reasons), while the Nginx version only supports one type of behavior.

Comment: This is correct; see [this SO question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485349/can-my-public-directory-be-a-symlink-with-rails-3-passenger-3-nginx-0-8/4689901#4689901) for a possible workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 2 of passenger the symlinks are not resolved on document root. You can change that setting with:

```
PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
```