# Sinatra tests always 404'ing

Tags: ruby, testing, sinatra, rack

I have a very simple Sinatra app which I'm having trouble testing.

Basically, every single request test returns a 404 when I know from testing in the browser that the request works fine.  Any ideas as to what the problem might be?

test_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RACK_ENV"] = 'test'

$: << File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../lib')
require 'app'
Sinatra::Synchrony.patch_tests!

class Test::Unit::TestCase
  include Rack::Test::Methods
end
```

app_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
class AppTest < Test::Unit::TestCase 
  def app
    @app ||= Sinatra::Application
  end
  def test_it_says_hello
    get "/"
    assert_equal 200,  last_response.status
  end
end
```

app.rb

```
$: << 'config'
require "rubygems" require "bundler"

ENV["RACK_ENV"] ||= "development" 
Bundler.require(:default, ENV["RACK_ENV"].to_sym) 
require ENV["RACK_ENV"]

class App < Sinatra::Base   register Sinatra::Synchrony
  get '/' do
    status 200
    'hello, I\'m bat shit crazy and ready to rock'   
  end
end
```

Gemfile

```
source :rubygems

gem 'daemons'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'sinatra-synchrony', :require => 'sinatra/synchrony' 
gem 'resque'
gem 'thin'

group :test do
  gem 'rack-test', :require => "rack/test"
  gem 'test-unit', :require => "test/unit" 
end
```

Why can I not get this normally very simple thing working?

Comment: Do you still get 404 when you replace `@app ||= Sinatra::Application` in your test with: `@app ||= App` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

app.rb

```
$: << 'config'
require "rubygems" require "bundler"

ENV["RACK_ENV"] ||= "development" Bundler.require(:default,
ENV["RACK_ENV"].to_sym) require ENV["RACK_ENV"]

class App < Sinatra::Base   
  register Sinatra::Synchrony
end

get '/' do
  status 200
  'hello, I\'m bat shit crazy and ready to rock'   
end
```

Comment: Using both the class/modular-style and the non-class-style in the same file/project doesn't seem very 'clean'. Maybe try what I wrote in my other comment!

Answer (score 7):

I had quite the same problem with only HTTP-404 coming in return.

I solved it with giving another return in the "app" function.

```
class IndexClassTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def app
      @app = Foxydeal #appname NOT Sinatra::Application
  end
...
```

1. Also

`Sinatra::Synchrony.patch_tests!`

seems to be obsolete.

Comment: This worked for me. I was using rspec and was able to get away with just returning the appname, without assigning it to an instance variable.

Answer (score 2):

Under your app_test.rb do this instead of what you have now:

```
  def app
     @app ||= App.new
  end
```

This will work with your your class style like you had it in the beginning, no need to switch to the non-class/modular style.

Answer (score 0):

It may seem logical, but are your routes configured correctly? If a route isn't correctly configured, it'll throw 404 errors left and right.

Comment: The page works in the browser.  Is there any other real route config in Sinatra?

Comment: Similar question with solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145819/why-am-i-getting-404-errors-with-sinatra-with-passenger-under-nginx

Answer (score 0):

You may simply do this:

```
class AppTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

def app
  Sinatra::Application
end
```

You can get a solid understanding of sinatra tests by reading [Learning From the Masters: Sinatra Internals](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/3/7/learning-from-the-masters-sinatra-internals) and [Rack::Test](https://github.com/brynary/rack-test)