# Use public directory on external server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, nginx, webserver

I have two Ruby on Rails 3.2 applications. They use Phusion Passenger, one with Nginx the other with Apache2.

How do you allow for an application (with Apache2) to access and have same permissions as the other application (with Nginx) to their PUBLIC directories?

I want to share the public directories between applications. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this but I think you could try to work with symlinks (given you have the privileges on the server to do this and the applications reside on the same server) or if they are on different servers look into a solution with SSH tunnels. Anyway I'm quite certain that you might run into trouble with files being overwritten - especially if you use asset precompilation.

Comment: I don't think files in the public directory are involved with Assets and precompilation. Reference?

Comment: We precompile the assets of our apps in production mode (manually via rake) and this creates an "assets" folder in the public directory. Major files like bootstrap css and js, image files etc. are stored there.

Comment: Here is a question quite similar to yours which deals with symlinking and problems with nginx: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485349/can-my-public-directory-be-a-symlink-with-rails-3-passenger-3-nginx-0-8?rq=1

Comment: My files being used in my public directory are outside of the assets folder. I have a folder named "files" that have my files. I still have assets but I do not want those to be shared.